# Scalable site, menu background disappears

Tags: html, css

I am new to the site and I am having trouble with a scalable website I am creating.  The problem appears when downsizing the screen to below 650px.  For some reason the background for my menu is disappearing.  I've gone over the code numerous times and cannot find my error.
Please help!

Here is the link to my page:  http://mnice.mydevryportfolio.com/portfolio/

Here is the Media CSS code that I have in place so far:

```
            /************************************************************************************
    smaller than 980
    *************************************************************************************/
    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

/* pagewrap */
#pagewrap {
    width: 95%;
}

/* content */
#content {
    width: 60%;
    padding: 3% 4%;
}

/* sidebar */
#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
}
#sidebar .widget {
    padding: 8% 7%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* embedded videos */
.video embed,
.video object,
.video iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 300px;
}

    }

            /************************************************************************************
    smaller than 650
    *************************************************************************************/
    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

/* header */
#header {
    height: auto;
}

/* search form */
#searchform {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 40px;
}
#searchform #s {
    width: 70px;
}
#searchform #s:focus {
    width: 150px;
}

/* main nav */
#main-nav {
    position: static;
}

/* site logo */
#site-logo {
    margin: 15px 100px 5px 0;
    position: static;
}

/* site description */
#site-description {
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    position: static;
}

/* content */
#content {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

/* sidebar */
#sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
#sidebar .widget {
    padding: 3% 4%;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

/* embedded videos */
.video embed,
.video object,
.video iframe {
    min-height: 250px;
}

    }

    /************************************************************************
    smaller than 560
    **************************************************************************/
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

/* disable webkit text size adjust (for iPhone) */
html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

/* main nav */
#main-nav a {
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 10px 8px;
}

    }
```

And then the main CSS Style Page:

```
    /************************************************************************
     RESET
     ****************************************************************************/
     html, body, address, blockquote, div, dl, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, p, pre, table, ul,
     dd, dt, li, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, button, del, ins, map, object,
     a, abbr, acronym, b, bdo, big, br, cite, code, dfn, em, i, img, kbd, q, samp, small, span,
     strong, sub, sup, tt, var, legend, fieldset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
     }

     img, fieldset {
border: 0;
     }

     /* set image max width to 100% */
     img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
     }

     /* set html5 elements to block */
     article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
         display: block;
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     GENERAL STYLING
     *************************************************************************************/
     body {
 background: url(images/background.png);
 font: .81em/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #000;
     }
     a {
 color: #026acb;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
     }
     a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
     }
     p {
margin: 0 0 1.2em;
padding: 0;
     }

     /* list */
     ul, ol {
margin: 1em 0 1.4em 24px;
padding: 0;
line-height: 140%;
     }
     li {
margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
padding: 0;
     }

     /* headings */
     h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
line-height: 1.4em;
margin: 20px 0 .4em;
color: #000;
     }
     h1 {
font-size: 2em;
     }
     h2 {
font-size: 1.6em;
     }
     h3 {
font-size: 1.4em;
     }
     h4 {
font-size: 1.2em;
     }
     h5 {
font-size: 1.1em;
     }
     h6 {
font-size: 1em;
     }

     /* reset webkit search input styles */
     input[type=search] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
outline: none;
     }
     input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration, 
     input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
display: none;
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     STRUCTURE
     *************************************************************************************/
     #pagewrap {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     HEADER
     *************************************************************************************/
     #header {
position: relative;
height: 180px;
     }

     /* site logo */
     #site-logo {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
     }
     #site-logo a {
font: bold 30px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
     }

     /* site description */
     #site-description {
font: italic 100%/130% "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 95px;
     }

     /* searchform */
     #searchform {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
bottom: 6px;
z-index: 100;
width: 160px;
     }
     #searchform #s {
width: 140px;
float: right;
background: #fff;
border: none;
padding: 6px 10px;
/* border radius */
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
/* box shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
/* transition */
-webkit-transition: width .7s;
-moz-transition: width .7s;
transition: width .7s;
     }

              /************************************************************************************
     MAIN NAVIGATION
     *************************************************************************************/
     #main-nav {
width: 100%;
background: #ccc;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 100;
/* gradient */
background: #6a6a6a url(images/nav-bar-bg.png) repeat-x;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b9b9b9), to(#6a6a6a));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b9b9b9,  #6a6a6a);
background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #b9b9b9, #6a6a6a);
/* rounded corner */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
/* box shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
     }
     #main-nav li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;
     }
     #main-nav li:first-child {
margin-left: 10px;
     }
     #main-nav a {
line-height: 100%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
display: block;
padding: 14px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     }
     #main-nav a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: #474747;
/* gradient */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#282828), to(#4f4f4f));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #282828,  #4f4f4f);
background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #282828, #4f4f4f);
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     CONTENT
     *************************************************************************************/
     #content {
         background-image: url(images/containerbackground_blur.png);
margin: 30px 0 30px;
padding: 20px 35px;
width: 700px;
float: left;
/* rounded corner */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
/* box shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
     }

     /* post */
     .post {
margin-bottom: 40px;
     }
     .post-title {
margin: 0 0 5px;
padding: 0;
font: bold 26px/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }
     .post-title a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
     }
     .post-meta {
margin: 0 0 10px;
font-size: 90%;
     }


     .main-image {
margin: 0 0 15px;
text-align: center;
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     SIDEBAR
     *************************************************************************************/
     #sidebar {
width: 200px;
float: right;
margin: 30px 0 30px;
     }
     .widget {
background: #fff;
margin: 0 0 30px;
padding: 10px 20px;
/* rounded corner */
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
/* box shadow */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
     }
     .widgettitle {
margin: 0 0 5px;
padding: 0; 
     }
     .widget ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
     }
     .widget li {
margin: 0;
padding: 6px 0;
list-style: none;
clear: both;
border-top: solid 1px #eee;
     }



     /************************************************************************************
     FOOTER
     *************************************************************************************/
     #footer {
clear: both;
color: #ccc;
font-size: 85%;
     }
     #footer a {
color: #fff;
     }

     /************************************************************************************
     CLEARFIX
     *************************************************************************************/
     .clearfix:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
     .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
     .clearfix { display: block; zoom: 1; }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello fellow DeVry student! It seems the problem is coming from changing the position with the media query and the `bottom: 0;`. Just a suggestion for this page http://mnice.mydevryportfolio.com/portfolio/aboutme.html, change the font type it is ruff on the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `overflow:hidden` to #main-nav or add float:left to the same ID, this will also fix the issue.

Reason of this issue is floated children of #main-nav and #main-nav itself is not, in this case the container div collapses. Using a 'clearfix' class or, as I mentioned, adding `overflow:hidden` or `float:left` will cause the container to contain the floated elements.

Answer (score 3):

media.css line 63 replace `position:static` with `bottom:auto;` in `#main-nav`

```
#main-nav {
    bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: This option worked as well!  Thanks for the quick response and great help!  Just another reason why I love StackOverFlow

Answer (score 1):

You changed the positioning context

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px)
#main-nav {
position: static;
}
```

If you remove `static` the bg color returns...then it's just a matter of tweaking the position values.

Comment: In addition to this don't set the header hegiht to auto give it some value like you do in main CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your media queries which are responsible for changing the layout on different screen sizes:

go ahead and add this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 650px)
#main-nav {
bottom: inherit;
}
```